# Animation On Scroll Up and Down Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey I am trying to replicate the on scroll animations on https://pixelgrade.com/demos/pile . I have tried ScrollMagic and Wow.js , but I am having great difficulty. I have found the vanilla code for detecting the direction in which the user is scrolling but that has some problems. If I set an on scroll listener, It would be animating every single thing on the page when the user scrolls. Any help would be appreciated , thank you.

Edit: I am referring to the image animations under the header. (The ones in a grid.)

Comment: Please share your code, it's hard to help you without it.

Comment: Check this http://codepen.io/aliencash/pen/zBaOJL

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Is this parallax?

Comment: this a simple example. just use position calculated on js.

Comment: u need a hover effect?

Comment: No, the effects that occur while you scroll. The ones that move elements in either up or down depending on your scroll.

Comment: ok. learn my example

Comment: What you are describing is not taking place on the site you linked to. I see a parallax animation but there is no animation happening to the images on scroll.

Comment: @APAD1 am I thinking of a css transition then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the Pile theme developers(the PHP one, unfortunately for you) and I can tell you that my colleague, Razvan Onofrei, created a jQuery plugin called [Rellax](https://pixelgrade.github.io/rellax) inspired by the development of [Pile2](https://pixelgrade.com/demos/pile2).

With this library, you should be able to replicate Pile's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Block `.item` scroll 3x speed from scrollbar. Show in a full screen.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var posTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
  
  document.getElementById('item').style.top =  1000 - parseInt(posTop * 3) + 'px';
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
  position: relative;
}

#item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="item"></div>
```